# How to have multiple lines in one line when writting nasm assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

For convenience I'd like to have multiple statements or (pseudo-)instructions written in one line.

for example in data section when initializing variables I would like to have this:

```
section .data 

var1 : dq  1.44         [special charakter here ]     var2 : dq 0.0
var3 : dq  1.44         [special charakter here ]     var4 : dq 0.0
var5 : dq  1.44         [special charakter here ]     var6 : dq 0.0
var7 : dq  1.44         [special charakter here ]     var8 : dq 0.0
```

instead of this :

```
var1 : dq 1.1
var2 : dq 1.2
var3 : dq 1.3
var4 : dq 1.4
var5 : dq 1.5
var6 : dq 1.6
var7 : dq 1.7
var8 : dq 1.8
```

is that possible? I've searched the NASM documentation but couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: You can do `dq 1,1, 1.2, 1.3` for example if you don't need separate labels on each element, but AFAIK NASM doesn't have a directive or instruction separator other than newline.  (GAS has `;` so you can do that in GAS.)

Comment: I believe this is not supported.  Consider making a macro if this is important to you.

Comment: ok  ,  macro works fine , i should have thought it earlier ! thanks   !!